# Adding a glm regression to a ggplot, where datapoints are colored after groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression

I am trying to visualize a regression by adding it to the data plot, but I want to color the data points after group (eight different groups) and then ggplot makes a glm line each group instead of one including all eight groups. Is there a way to show all eight groups (color the data points) and put the regression line on top?

I‘ve included an image of what it looks like when I use this syntax:

```
ggplot(data=Sig, aes(x=LogDistance, y=Amplitude,colour=DyrN)) + geom_point() + ylab("Intensitet af kald") + xlab("LogDistance")+geom_smooth(method=glm,data = Sig)
```

In the plot I would like to include the data points colored for groups, a regression that has been computed in the lme4 package, as well as include a second line that is a theoretical relationship, but I would like to have the shaded area surrounding the glm line.

Anybody that can help?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the colour aesthetic only to the geom_point:

```
ggplot(data=Sig, aes(x=LogDistance, y=Amplitude)) + 
    geom_point(aes(colour=DyrN)) + 
    geom_smooth(method=glm,data = Sig) +
    ylab("Intensitet af kald") + 
    xlab("LogDistance")
```